# Fiddler fail to access HTTPS page

Tags: ssl, https, certificate, fiddler

Page creating required cookies: http://ticket.urbtix.hk/internet/en_US

Problematic https => https://ticket.urbtix.hk/internet/login/transaction

When I try to access the http page via Fiddler using Firefox, fiddler can successfully capture the http packet.

But when I access the HTTPS page in the server, Firefox will prompt "The connection was reset".

I have setup Firefox to trust the cert from Fiddler and I can successfully connect to HTTPS page in other server, like google.com.

It looks to me the server ticket.urbtix.hk only trust specific client certificate. I try to extract the cert from Firefox and attach to fiddler, but it does not work for me.

Comment: I can not see any problems with the server and it does not need any client certificates. Did you get any error messages, can you do a packet capture in between fiddler and the server?

Comment: probably you can try this page: https://ticket.urbtix.hk/internet/login/transaction. but this would require cookies from the first page.
from Fiddler, it can only capture the CONNECTS packet

Comment: The server does not need client certificates. Again, look at error messages you get and make packet captures if you try to get help. Also, the server is reaaally slow, so you might get connection resets because of this too.

Comment: The serve is fast in my region. When I don't connect via fiddler, the https can be connect and show in Firefox. But when I connect via fiddler, the connection is reset

Comment: I just try connect via charlesproxy, it prompt the handshaking part fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've confirmed that this is the server bug whereby [the server foolishly sends](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fiddler/2012/03/28/net-https-connections-timeout-on-sni-tls-warning/) a non-fatal SNI warning.

The workaround is simple. In Fiddler, click `Rules` > `Customize Rules`.

Scroll to the `OnBeforeRequest` method. Add the following code:

```
    if (oSession.host.Contains("urbtix.hk"))
    {
        oSession["X-OverrideSSLProtocols"] = "ssl3";   
    }
```

Comment: hi eric, your workaround works perfectly before. but when i try access the page using fiddler again, the same issue happens again. Do you have any further insight?

Comment: @Steven: I'm not sure I understand the question. The workaround above no longer works in some cases because many servers have disabled SSL3.  See the `SNI Hack` section of http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/15-04-27/what-s-new-in-fiddler-4-5-1 for more information and other options.

Answer (score 1):

I reset all the fiddler certificates and it seemed to work

Fiddler 4.6.1.5+

1. Click **Tools** > **Fiddler Options**
2. Click the **HTTPS** tab
3. Ensure that the text says **Certificates generated by CertEnroll engine**
4. Click **Actions** > **Reset Certificates**. This may take a minute.
5. Accept all prompts

[image]
(for me there was approximately 6 prompts asking me for permission to remove and add stuff)

https://textslashplain.com/2015/10/30/reset-fiddlers-https-certificates/

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try with other browsers to eliminate FF related bug. Also try changing following.

1. Reuse client connection
2. Reuse server connection

Its working perfect at my end and can't replicate issue.